# Accessing Geoserver plugins through the REST API

Tags: python, geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, image-pyramids

I am writing Python scripts to automate the creation of Geoserver layers. For this [the gsconfig module](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gsconfig) has been invaluable, but I often need to execute operations that are handled by plugins, most often the ImagePyramid one.

I suppose I could use the REST API but I'm not clear how to access the functionalities of installed plugins - in my case ImagePyramid.

Editing to add a more focused reformulation of my question: how do I call on the functionalities of the ImagePyramid plugin using the REST API in Python? More generally, how do I figure it out for any given plugin?

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are asking here. You're describing a problem, but something more specific would probably help. Can you show a specific issue, and what you've already tried?

Comment: I added a more focused reformulation in my original post.